# UITableView Footer Not Appearing

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a uitableview with multiple sections. I am trying to add a nib to the tableview's footer. If I programmatically create a view it appears but I am unable to put the nib in the footer. When that NSBundle line is commented out the TV appears perfectly fine, but if I uncomment it I only see a black screen in the simulator.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"footerView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

//    CGRect footerRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 100);    
//    UIView *wrapperView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:footerRect];
//
//    UILabel *tableFooter = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:footerRect];
//    tableFooter.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
//    tableFooter.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
//    tableFooter.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
//    tableFooter.text = @"test";
//
//    [wrapperView addSubview:tableFooter];
//
//    self.tableView.tableFooterView = wrapperView;
}
```

[nib screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqRmC.png)

Am I instantiating the nib incorrectly?

Comment: Are you sure that the last top level object in your nib is a view? If so then maybe it isn't configured the way you assume it is (its frame is different, stuff that usually was done in awakeFromNib and the like didn't happen,...)

Comment: Good suggestion. That is carry over from my real project but yes I moved that NSBundle line to an array. Now that nib is the only entry in the array and I am still having the same issue.

Comment: Mind elaborating on the frame thing?

Comment: Wait, a nib and a view are two different things. The `loadNibNamed:owner:options:` methods gives you an array of objects (of type `id`). Namely, all objects that are on the top level of the nib (excluding proxies like file owner). You then get the last object of it, and what that is depends on what you dragged into the nib in Interface Builder. It could be anything, not necessarily a view. Can you post a screenshot of your nib file opened in Interface Builder, with the left menu open to see what's in it? The frame thing is just an idea I had, but that also depends on the nib.

Comment: added the screenshot. The nib file owner is also set to the tableview's controller as the nib does not have any class files.

Comment: Okay, I've tried it myself and for me it works. I'd recommend ensuring you get a view in that array, though. The frame thing shouldn't be an issue, as the screenshot makes me think you have a freeform view, so it has a fixed size, correct? I noticed something unusual, though, you called the nib "footerView". With a non capital f at the start? Usually the xib files are capitalized by most people, like classes. You do have a footerView.xib file in your projects target, right?

Comment: File is def part of the build. Thanks for the note about the capital letter in my real project it is capitalized just didn't in this test proj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And as an actual answer, because it allows me to post code. I set up my own little demo project, with a very simple "FooterView.xib" file (created from XCode's template for a view resource). I set the view in it to freeform and gave it a small enough frame so it doesn't kill the table visually. Then in my table's ViewController I did:

```
UIView *test;
NSArray *results = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FooterView" owner:self options:nil];
test = [results lastObject];
self.tableView.tableFooterView = test;
```

Splitting the lines up a bit allowed me to debug (I set a breakpoint before `self.tableView.tableFooterView = test` and ensured that test was a view (with the frame I defined in the xib, so I could recognize it).

Edit: Here's my test app [repo](https://github.com/GeroHerkenrath/XibViewLoadingForSO).

Comment: I am still seeing the same issue using your code. Would you mind sticking the proj on github or anywhere else?

Comment: I edited my answer with a link to github. I hope it helps, if not I might check tomorrow again (now is time for sleeping here :) )